# How do I convert a large number into a number with fewer digits?

Tags: python, numbers, type-conversion

I am having trouble converting my data into units of billion.  Right now, my data consists of the whole number, for example 12,000,000,000.  Where I would just like it to be in units of 12 billion.  Now, I don't want it to say billion, I just want the number to come out as 12.

```
wb = UpdateWorkbook(r'C:\Users\vince\Project\Spreadsheet.xlsx', worksheet=1)
df_2 = fd_frames['income_statement']
a = df_2.values[0].astype('int64') #This is where I get the error
b = a/(1000000000)  #This is what I was thinking of doing, but it doesn't work
wb['M6:T6'] = df_2.values[0] #
wb.save()
```

I keep getting multiply errors whenever I try to convert my list into an integer, here are some of the few:

```
 ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Revenue'
 OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long
```

I believe my biggest trouble is the first error because I have one word in my list and all the other are numbers or values.

Comment: Perhaps you could trim this code down for us to just a minimal few lines that reproduce the problem?

Comment: the conversion of number is correct,  but the error is for you were converting `Revenue` as string to int,  which never been possible, thats what the error you were getting ,  check the value of `df_2.values[0]` @vdub32

Comment: `a = df_2.values[0].astype('int64');
b = a/(1000000000)` Specify an example value which would be stored in `a`

Comment: @Sanket, that is the issue I am running into.  One of my values is a string and all the other values are integers.  Is there any way around this problem?  Do I have to create some type of for loop?

Comment: no instead of `Revenue` , try to get value for it  bcoz conversion of string to int never possible @vdub32

Comment: @Sanket, I don't understand what you mean by try to get value for it?  So since it is not possible to convert string to int, then I need another approach or solution to my problem.  Do you have any ideas or recommendations?